# Scala how to repeat the first element of Array until Array.size reach a certain number

Tags: scala

I have a Array of length 3 say `Array(3,4,5)` and I have a target length which is an `Int` say 7. How do I pad the `Array` with it's first element until the length of the `Array` reaches the `Int`?

```
val A = Array(3,4,5)
val T = 7
//Desired output Array(3,3,3,3,3,4,5)
```

My current method:

```
val difflength = T - A.size
val firstElement = A.head
val PadArray = (for(i <- 0 to difflength) yield firstElement).toArray
PadArray ++ A
```

Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Array`'s `fill` method](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.Array$@fill[T](n:Int)(elem:=>T)(implicitevidence$9:scala.reflect.ClassTag[T]):Array[T]) comes in handy for this:

```
val a = Array(3,4,5)
val b = {
  val t = 7
  val diffLength = t - a.size
  val firstElement = a.head
  Array.fill(diffLength)(firstElement) ++ a
}
```

Result:

```
scala> b
res0: Array[Int] = Array(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5)
```

Comment: ah, fill is better than the for loop which I am currently using, good one.